# R: Turning columns into rows (appending the columns)

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, append, pivot

I've the following dataset and I would like to find out how to switch the column into rows in R.

| Pet Shop | Year | dog | fish | turtle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021 | 275 | 20 | NA |
| A | 2020 | 250 | NA | 50 |
| A | 2019 | NA | NA | NA |
| B | 2021 | 350 | 75 | NA |
| B | 2020 | NA | 55 | 85 |
| B | 2019 | NA | 75 | NA |
| C | 2021 | 280 | NA | NA |
| C | 2020 | NA | NA | NA |
| C | 2019 | NA | 60 | NA |

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can append the columns as rows?

| Pet Shop | Year | Animal | Prices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021 | dog | 275 |
| A | 2021 | fish | 20 |
| A | 2021 | turtle | NA |
| A | 2020 | dog | 250 |
| A | 2020 | fish | NA |
| A | 2020 | turtle | 50 |
| A | 2019 | dog | NA |
| A | 2019 | fish | NA |
| A | 2019 | turtle | NA |
| B | 2021 | dog | 350 |
| B | 2021 | fish | 75 |
| B | 2021 | turtle | NA |
| B | 2020 | dog | NA |
| B | 2020 | fish | 55 |
| B | 2020 | turtle | 85 |

... and onwards

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
          Pet.Shop = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
              Year = c(2021L,2020L,2019L,2021L,
                       2020L,2019L,2021L,2020L,2019L),
               dog = c(275L, 250L, NA, 350L, NA, NA, 280L, NA, NA),
              fish = c(20L, NA, NA, 75L, 55L, 75L, NA, NA, 60L),
            turtle = c(NA, 50L, NA, NA, 85L, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

df %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = dog:turtle,
               names_to = "Animal",
               values_to = "Prices")

#> # A tibble: 27 x 4
#>    Pet.Shop  Year Animal Prices
#>    <chr>    <int> <chr>   <int>
#>  1 A         2021 dog       275
#>  2 A         2021 fish       20
#>  3 A         2021 turtle     NA
#>  4 A         2020 dog       250
#>  5 A         2020 fish       NA
#>  6 A         2020 turtle     50
#>  7 A         2019 dog        NA
#>  8 A         2019 fish       NA
#>  9 A         2019 turtle     NA
#> 10 B         2021 dog       350
#> # ... with 17 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>